# Silverlight 4/5 and recording video using webcam and mic

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, webcam

Is there any support for video+audio recording using webcam and mic in silverlight.

I want to record the video with audio using silverlight and store at the server side using wcf  service.